# Javascript/jQuery height calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for a way, in javascript, to calculate the size of the browser `(px)` then calculate the size of a `<div>` taking away `50px` from that full screen size:

E.g.

```
Browser screen size: 800px (Height)
Existing <div> that is always 50px (Height)
Leaves 750px (Height) for the remaining <div> to fill the page.
```

Then take that `750px` and apply it as inline style:

```
<div style="height: 50px">
<img src="banner.png" />
</div>

<div style="height: x">
This fills the remainder of the page
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to check other properties (`margin`, `padding` and `border`) that can contribute to a DIV's height, use `outerHeight` - http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean document height, not browser height.  You can do this using something like the following:

```
$("#div2").height($(document).height() - 50);

// or for more dynamicity
$("#div2").height($(document).height() - $("#div1").height());
```

If you did mean browser height and not document height, substitute `$(document)` with `$(window)`.

Comment: Can you add another element to subtract: $("#div2").height($(document).height() - $("#div1") - $("#div3").height());

Comment: @danit: if you want to, sure.  Add as many elements as you like.  Make sure you're calling the `height()` method on them, though -- eg. `$("#div2").height($(document).height() - $("#div1").height() - $("#div3").height());`

Comment: Thanks, another question. Possible to resize #div2 when the document is resized? Tried .resize but thats for the window not the document.

Comment: @danit, when the window resizes, so should the document.  So you would use `$(window).resize(function () { /* do calculation here */ }`.  Apparently, in Firefox the `resize` event will only fire when you finish resizing.  In other browsers it fires as you are dragging the window.